# Using multiple scores with FB.API on Facebook

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I am currently using FB.API to post player score into Facebook. The docs I am using are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API). When I am using it for one score, it works perfectly fine. However, I am starting to face problems when I want to use second, third.., etc. scores for one player (lets say first score tells how many monsters player has killed, while the second score tells how much gold player collected). Any ideas how to do that (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Facebook doesn't allow more than 1 score per app. So I don't think you will be able to achieve what you want.

You might as well consider using a service like Parse (since it also belongs to Facebook if I'm not mistaken), or implement your own leaderboards in your server (there are a few tutorials, and it's not a hard thing to do). The only downside to this, is that you won't get the timeline stories "You have passed a friend on XGame" and the bar charts below.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look into Parse, as it seems to have quite well developed set of functionalities for Unity. P.S. Do you know what "tag" would be best to chose here to ask Unity-Parse-sdk related questions?

Comment: [parse.com] is the appropriate tag I believe :) Doesn't have one specific for unity, but most of the functionality is the same cross-platform, since they are just API calls.

Comment: So I seen there are quite a lot of updates for Unity-Facebook sdk, so wondering if there are any upcoming updates/plans to bring multiple scores possible? Or we are still heavily bound to third party services like Parse, Amazon S3, etc to save player scores?